# Conflicts between vue scoped styles and bootstrap

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-style-loader

I'm developing an embedded plugin in vuejs.
In dev mode this plugin is embedded in a lorem ipsum html page that load bootstrap.

I just noticed that one of my element inside the plugin with a "close" class is affected by a bootstrap close class. I'd like to fully scoped my Vue.js styles in order to not be affected by external styles (since this plugin will be embedded by customers) but also want my internal scoped style to not leak outside the plugin and affects my customer pages.

I'd like to know if there is a way to do so for example by overriding class names with unique ids during webpack compilation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your plugin in a `div#myId` and then use your scoped css to target elements inside that `div#myId`.

In your case you could target the element with the "close" tag like so:

```
div#myID .close{
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I do. But it doesn't prevent external css to impact my `.close` element, which is my problem !

Comment: If you are using the same class names as Bootstrap and don't want any conflict with their classes, why don't you use another class name?